# Argparse: Required argument 'y' if 'x' is present

Tags: python, argparse

I have a requirement as follows:

```
./xyifier --prox --lport lport --rport rport
```

for the argument prox , I use action='store_true' to check if it is present or not. 
I do not require any of the arguments. But, if --prox is set I *require* rport and lport as well. Is there an easy way of doing this with argparse without writing custom conditional coding.

More Code:

```
non_int.add_argument('--prox', action='store_true', help='Flag to turn on proxy')
non_int.add_argument('--lport', type=int, help='Listen Port.')
non_int.add_argument('--rport', type=int, help='Proxy port.')
```

Comment: Plugging, but I wanted to mention my library [joffrey](https://github.com/supposedly/joffrey). Lets you do what this question wants, for example, without making you validate everything yourself (as in the accepted answer) or rely on a loopholey hack (as in the second-highest-voted response).

Comment: For anyone arriving here, another amazing solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210638/6045800

Answer (score 191, accepted):

No, there isn't any option in argparse to make mutually *inclusive* sets of options.

The simplest way to deal with this would be:

```
if args.prox and (args.lport is None or args.rport is None):
    parser.error("--prox requires --lport and --rport.")
```

Actually there's already an open PR with an enhancement proposal :
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/55797

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing

Comment: Thank you for `parser.error` method, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: shouldn't you use 'or'? after all you require both args

`if args.prox and (args.lport is None or args.rport is None):`

Comment: Instead of `args.lport is None`, you can simply use `not args.lport`. I think it's a little more pythonic.

Comment: That would stop you from setting `--lport` or `--rport` to `0`, which might be a valid input to the program.

Comment: Interdependence of fields seems like a good feature to have within argparse itself though.

Comment: What is "parser" an instance of? I assumed it was a RequestParser instance, but doesn't seem so? Thanks.

Comment: The "parser" object is an instance of [argparse.ArgumentParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects).

Comment: @rkachach: your edit mentioning an MR that adds this to argparse might be better as a comment than an addition to the answer - it's older than this question and doesn't seem to have any likelyhood of being merged.

Comment: @borntyping I think it adds value in the sense it's something that they didn't merge for some reason. I can convert it my edit o answer if more people think that it adds no value.

Answer (score 87):

You're talking about having conditionally required arguments. Like @borntyping said you could check for the error and do `parser.error()`, or you could just apply a requirement related to `--prox` when you add a new argument.

A simple solution for your example could be:

```
non_int.add_argument('--prox', action='store_true', help='Flag to turn on proxy')
non_int.add_argument('--lport', required='--prox' in sys.argv, type=int)
non_int.add_argument('--rport', required='--prox' in sys.argv, type=int)
```

This way `required` receives either `True` or `False` depending on whether the user as used `--prox`. This also guarantees that `-lport` and `-rport` have an independent behavior between each other.

Comment: Note that `ArgumentParser` can be used to parse arguments from a list other than `sys.argv`, which case this would fail.

Comment: Also this will fail if the `--prox=<value>` syntax is used.

Comment: then `required='--prox' in " ".join(sys.argv)`

Comment: There also several cases where the parser is constructed before its usage, as in [Django commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.create_parser), preventing this approach to be useful

Answer (score 20):

How about using [`parser.parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) method and then adding the `--lport` and `--rport` args as required args if `--prox` is present.

```
# just add --prox arg now
non_int = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="stackoverflow question", 
                                  usage="%(prog)s [-h] [--prox --lport port --rport port]")
non_int.add_argument('--prox', action='store_true', 
                     help='Flag to turn on proxy, requires additional args lport and rport')
opts, rem_args = non_int.parse_known_args()
if opts.prox:
    non_int.add_argument('--lport', required=True, type=int, help='Listen Port.')
    non_int.add_argument('--rport', required=True, type=int, help='Proxy port.')
    # use options and namespace from first parsing
    non_int.parse_args(rem_args, namespace = opts)
```

Also keep in mind that you can supply the namespace `opts` generated after the first parsing while parsing the remaining arguments the second time. That way, in the the end, after all the parsing is done, you'll have a single namespace with all the options.

Drawbacks:

- If `--prox` is not present the other two dependent options aren't even present in the namespace. Although based on your use-case, if `--prox` is not present, what happens to the other options is irrelevant.
- Need to modify usage message as parser doesn't know full structure
- `--lport` and `--rport` don't show up in help message

Comment: This looks very neat. Unfortunately in cases where `--prox` is a required parameter, the call to `parse_args(…)` fails since the required parameter is not in the list of `rem_args`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "`--prox` is a required parameter", do you mean `--prox` isn't an optional argument? Could you please elaborate (maybe with an example)?

Comment: Certainly, [here](https://gist.github.com/hoehermann/08d56f62a0b04e88697feba2f362884b) you are. This illustrates the case where the common parameter is not a flag, but a choice. I now realize that the question specifically asks for the `store_true` variant, so the answer is still very good.

Comment: Hmm, that is an interesting situation indeed. I tried playing around with `parse_known_args` and `parse_args` and the best thing I could come up with looked super hacky. So, I think, in this situation I would go with borntyping's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414853/1614140)

Answer (score 10):

Do you use `lport` when `prox` is not set.  If not, why not make `lport` and `rport` arguments of `prox`?  e.g.

```
parser.add_argument('--prox', nargs=2, type=int, help='Prox: listen and proxy ports')
```

That saves your users typing.  It is just as easy to test `if args.prox is not None:` as `if args.prox:`.

Comment: For completeness of the example, when your nargs is > 1, you'll get a list in the parsed argument etc., which you can address in the usual manners. E.g., `a,b = args.prox`, `a = args.prox[0]`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer worked great for me! Since all code is broken without tests here is how I tested the accepted answer. `parser.error()` does not raise an `argparse.ArgumentError` error it instead exits the process. You have to test for `SystemExit`.

with pytest

```
import pytest
from . import parse_arguments  # code that rasises parse.error()


def test_args_parsed_raises_error():
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
        parse_arguments(["argument that raises error"])
```

with unittests

```
from unittest import TestCase
from . import parse_arguments  # code that rasises parse.error()

class TestArgs(TestCase):

    def test_args_parsed_raises_error():
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
            parse_arguments(["argument that raises error"])
```

inspired from: [Using unittest to test argparse - exit errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028204/using-unittest-to-test-argparse-exit-errors)

Comment: `"Since all code is broken without tests"` LOL who said that ?

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this:

```
if t or x or y:
    assert t and x and y, f"args: -t, -x and -y should be given together"
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put this logic?