# Python Argparse conditionally required arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have done as much research as possible but I haven't found the best way to make certain cmdline arguments necessary only under certain conditions, in this case only if other arguments have been given. Here's what I want to do at a very basic level:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
p.add_argument('--argument', required=False)
p.add_argument('-a', required=False) # only required if --argument is given
p.add_argument('-b', required=False) # only required if --argument is given
```

From what I have seen, other people seem to just add their own check at the end:

```
if args.argument and (args.a is None or args.b is None):
    # raise argparse error here
```

Is there a way to do this natively within the argparse package?

Comment: Have you looked at `argparse` subparsers? They will allow you to do things like `$ git commit <commit args only>` or `$ git merge <merge args only>`.

Comment: Joel, thanks for the comment. I have seen the subparser aspect of argparse but I was hoping to do this without positional arguments. If that's the only way though it's not a big deal

Comment: Can `--a` and `--b` be given independently?

Answer (score 114):

I've been searching for a simple answer to this kind of question for some time. All you need to do is check if `'--argument'` is in `sys.argv`, so basically for your code sample you could just do:

```
import argparse
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
    p.add_argument('--argument', required=False)
    p.add_argument('-a', required='--argument' in sys.argv) #only required if --argument is given
    p.add_argument('-b', required='--argument' in sys.argv) #only required if --argument is given
    args = p.parse_args()
```

This way `required` receives either `True` or `False` depending on whether the user as used `--argument`. Already tested it, seems to work and guarantees that `-a` and `-b` have an independent behavior between each other.

Comment: Simple, concise, and FREAKING WORKS!

Comment: Is there a way to make this throw an error if `-a` is given but `--argument` is not present?

Comment: @VivekSubramanian You could do that after `args = p.parse_args()`

Comment: This would be incompatible with positional arguments cause it ignores the end-of-options marker, `--`. E.g. `sys.argv[1:] = ['--', '--argument', 'foobar']` -> `-a` and `-b` shouldn't be required, but they are.

Comment: also this will not show in -h/--help message correctly as it does not have sufficient information at that time! so it might be a little confusing for the user

Comment: This solution is great, but it can't satisfy situations where the parser is constructed before its usage as in Django commands

Comment: Another corner-case problem with this solution: `--arg` can also be used in place of `--argument` and if that happens, the subsequent conditions are completely bypassed.

Answer (score 17):

You can implement a check by providing a custom action for `--argument`, which will take an additional keyword argument to specify which other action(s) should become required if `--argument` is used.

```
import argparse

class CondAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
        x = kwargs.pop('to_be_required', [])
        super(CondAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)
        self.make_required = x

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        for x in self.make_required:
            x.required = True
        try:
            return super(CondAction, self).__call__(parser, namespace, values, option_string)
        except NotImplementedError:
            pass

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
x = p.add_argument("--a")
p.add_argument("--argument", action=CondAction, to_be_required=[x])
```

The exact definition of `CondAction` will depend on what, exactly, `--argument` should do. But, for example, if `--argument` is a regular, take-one-argument-and-save-it type of action, then just inheriting from `argparse._StoreAction` should be sufficient.

In the example parser, we save a reference to the `--a` option inside the `--argument` option, and when `--argument` is seen on the command line, it sets the `required` flag on `--a` to `True`. Once all the options are processed, `argparse` verifies that any option marked as required has been set.

Comment: As written it doesn't work because `Action.__call__` returns a `not implement` error.  But the basic idea of tweaking the `required` attribute of `x` should work.

Comment: Good point. If you inherit from `argparse.Action`, then there's no need to call the (unimplemented) parent-class `__call__`. If you inherit from one of the other `Action` subclass's, you should. (As a compromise, I edited the answer to leave the superclass call in place, but catch and ignore the `NotImplementedError`.)

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple and clean solution with these advantages:

- No ambiguity and loss of functionality caused by oversimplified parsing using the `in sys.argv` test.
- No need to implement a special `argparse.Action` or `argparse.UsageGroup` class.
- Simple usage even for multiple and complex deciding arguments.

I noticed just one considerable drawback (which some may find desirable): The help text changes according to the state of the deciding arguments.

The idea is to use `argparse` twice:

1. Parse the deciding arguments instead of the oversimplified use of the `in sys.argv` test. For this we use a short parser not showing help and the method `.parse_known_args()` which ignores unknown arguments.
2. Parse everything normally while reusing the parser from the first step as a parent and having the results from the first parser available.

```py
import argparse

# First parse the deciding arguments.
deciding_args_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
deciding_args_parser.add_argument(
        '--argument', required=False, action='store_true')
deciding_args, _ = deciding_args_parser.parse_known_args()

# Create the main parser with the knowledge of the deciding arguments.
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='...', parents=[deciding_args_parser])
parser.add_argument('-a', required=deciding_args.argument)
parser.add_argument('-b', required=deciding_args.argument)
arguments = parser.parse_args()

print(arguments)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your post parsing test is fine, especially if testing for defaults with `is None` suits your needs.

http://bugs.python.org/issue11588 `'Add "necessarily inclusive" groups to argparse'` looks into implementing tests like this using the `groups` mechanism (a generalization of mutuall_exclusive_groups).

I've written a set of `UsageGroups` that implement tests like `xor` (mutually exclusive), `and`, `or`, and `not`.  I thought those where comprehensive, but I haven't been able to express your case in terms of those operations. (looks like I need `nand` - not and, see below)

This script uses a custom `Test` class, that essentially implements your post-parsing test.  `seen_actions` is a list of Actions that the parse has seen.

```
class Test(argparse.UsageGroup):
    def _add_test(self):
        self.usage = '(if --argument then -a and -b are required)'
        def testfn(parser, seen_actions, *vargs, **kwargs):
            "custom error"
            actions = self._group_actions
            if actions[0] in seen_actions:
                if actions[1] not in seen_actions or actions[2] not in seen_actions:
                    msg = '%s - 2nd and 3rd required with 1st'
                    self.raise_error(parser, msg)
            return True
        self.testfn = testfn
        self.dest = 'Test'
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.UsageGroupHelpFormatter)
g1 = p.add_usage_group(kind=Test)
g1.add_argument('--argument')
g1.add_argument('-a')
g1.add_argument('-b')
print(p.parse_args())
```

Sample output is:

```
1646:~/mypy/argdev/usage_groups$ python3 issue25626109.py --arg=1 -a1
usage: issue25626109.py [-h] [--argument ARGUMENT] [-a A] [-b B]
                        (if --argument then -a and -b are required)
issue25626109.py: error: group Test: argument, a, b - 2nd and 3rd required with 1st
```

`usage` and error messages still need work.  And it doesn't do anything that post-parsing test can't.

---

Your test raises an error if `(argument & (!a or !b))`.  Conversely, what is allowed is `!(argument & (!a or !b)) = !(argument & !(a and b))`.  By adding a `nand` test to my `UsageGroup` classes, I can implement your case as:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.UsageGroupHelpFormatter)
g1 = p.add_usage_group(kind='nand', dest='nand1')
arg = g1.add_argument('--arg', metavar='C')
g11 = g1.add_usage_group(kind='nand', dest='nand2')
g11.add_argument('-a')
g11.add_argument('-b')
```

The usage is (using `!()` to mark a 'nand' test):

```
usage: issue25626109.py [-h] !(--arg C & !(-a A & -b B))
```

I think this is the shortest and clearest way of expressing this problem using general purpose usage groups.

---

In my tests, inputs that parse successfully are:

```
''
'-a1'
'-a1 -b2'
'--arg=3 -a1 -b2'
```

Ones that are supposed to raise errors are:

```
'--arg=3'
'--arg=3 -a1'
'--arg=3 -b2'
```

Answer (score 5):

For arguments I've come up with a quick-n-dirty solution like this. 
Assumptions:  (1) '--help' should display help and not complain about required argument and (2) we're parsing `sys.argv`

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
p.add_argument('-required', ..., required = '--help' not in sys.argv )
```

This can easily be modified to match a specific setting.
For required positionals (which will become unrequired if e.g. '--help' is given on the command line) I've come up with the following: [positionals do not allow for a `required=...` keyword arg!]

```
p.add_argument('pattern', ..., narg = '+' if '--help' not in sys.argv else '*' )
```

basically this turns the number of required occurrences of 'pattern' on the command line from one-or-more into zero-or-more in case '--help' is specified.

Comment: I don't mind a downvote or two but I'd like to know why, especially since another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210638/26083 (with upvote 5 at this point) basically does the same

Answer (score 2):

Until http://bugs.python.org/issue11588 is solved, I'd just use [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argumentparser#nargs):

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
p.add_argument('--arguments', required=False, nargs=2, metavar=('A', 'B'))
```

This way, if anybody supplies `--arguments`, it will have 2 values.

Maybe its CLI result is less readable, but code is much smaller. You can fix that with good docs/help.

Answer (score 1):

Add additional simple "pre"parser to check --argument, but use parse_known_args() .

```
pre = argparse.ArgumentParser()
pre.add_argument('--argument', required=False, action='store_true', default=False)
args_pre=pre.parse_known_args()

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--argument', required=False)
p.add_argument('-a', required=args_pre.argument)
p.add_argument('-b', required=not args_pre.argument)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really the same as @Mira 's answer but I wanted to show it for the case where when an option is given that an extra arg is required:

For instance, if `--option foo` is given then some args are also required that are not required if `--option bar` is given:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--option', required=True,
        help='foo and bar need different args')

    if 'foo' in sys.argv:
        parser.add_argument('--foo_opt1', required=True,
           help='--option foo requires "--foo_opt1"')
        parser.add_argument('--foo_opt2', required=True,
           help='--option foo requires "--foo_opt2"')
        ...

    if 'bar' in sys.argv:
        parser.add_argument('--bar_opt', required=True,
           help='--option bar requires "--bar_opt"')
        ...
```

It's not perfect - for instance `proggy --option foo --foo_opt1 bar` is ambiguous but for what I needed to do its ok.