# Python3 Argparse: argument only required if another one has a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have two flags, both of which require a value -i [value] & -k [value].

Only if I use -i importantValue, will the -k [value] flag be required.

Is it possible to specify this with argparse? If so, how?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626109/python-argparse-conditionally-required-arguments

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414060/argparse-required-argument-y-if-x-is-present

Comment: To add to the earlier answers, the only thing new is that the value of `-i` matters.  That's all the more reason to do your own checking after parsing.  Since the user can specify `-i` after `-k`, you don't know its final value until all of the values are parsed.