# How to create Argument Parser

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am new to `argparser` in python . I am trying to create `argparser` for file which contains two functions `download` and `upload` file on/from box. It will do only one functionality at once according according to that i am trying to create parser for that file as follows but it's not working for me:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download or Upload file on box.')
    parser.add_argument('-df', '--download', required=True,
                        help='download file box')
    parser.add_argument('-uf', '--upload', nargs='+', required=True,
                        help='upload file of box')
    parser.add_argument('-fp', '--filepath', required=True,
                        help='file path to upload(which file to upload) or download(where to download file)')
    parser.add_argument('-fn', '--filename', required=True,
                        help='what should be the name of file on box')
    parser.add_argument('-fi', '--fileid', required=True,
                        help='file id of file to download from box')

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

**NOTE** :- every time only `-df` or `-uf` options will be there, `-fp` is mandatory for both and if it is `-df` then `-fi` is only option and it is  mandatory and if `-uf` then `-fn` is only option and it's mandatory.

How do I achieve this, following are example how will i pass argument to file

`pyhton abc.py -df -fp 'Download/boxfile/xyz.txt' -fi 123`

`python abc.py -uf -fp 'Download/boxfile/xyz.txt' -fn 'qwe.txt'`

Comment: Could you explain your NOTE paragraph more clearly? It is difficult to follow

Comment: rather than down voting question you can do hard work to comment and ask more question . as i dint think `argsparser` document is more understandable for fresher.

Comment: @khelwood, Thanks bro !! as I want to two options `-df`(download file) and `-uf`(upload file) only one at time.  `-fp`(file path) will be mandatory for both `-df` and `-uf`. The options `-fn`(file name) and `-fi`(file id) will be depends on `-df` and `-uf`,  if `-df` then only `-fi` is the option and it's mandatory  and If `-uf` then only `-fn` is the option ans it's mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written all 5 of the arguments are `required` - you made that explicit.  If that's what you really want, all the rest of the question is irrelevant.  You'll have to provide all 5 regardless.

But the comments indicate that you want to use either `-df` or `-uf`, but probably not both (though that bit's unclear).

While there is a `mutually_exclusive_mechanism` in `argparse`, there isn't a `inclusive` equivalent - something that says if `-f` is present, then `-g` must also be given.

But `subparsers` mechanism can be used that way.   You could define an `download` subparser, with a required `-fi` argument.  And an `upload` with its own argument.

Another option is to set `-df` to take 2 arguments (`nargs=2`), both its `box` and its `file`.

If `-df` and `-uf` are mutually exclusive, why not use the same argument for the name of the file?  That is, replace `-fn` and `-fi` with one `file` argument.

Another option is to make all (or most) of the arguments not-required, and check for the correct combinations after parsing.  It's easier to implement complicated logic in your own code than to force `argparse` to do it for you.

e.g.

```
 if args.download is not None:    # not default
     <check for `args.filename`> etc
```

It can also be a good idea to provide defaults for optional arguments.  That way the code can run even if the user doesn't provide all items.

On a matter of style.  Short option flags, with on `-` are usually a single character.  `-d`, `-u`, etc.  The ability to combine several into one string only works in that case, e.g. `-df foo`.  In this case it probably doesn't matter since none of your arguments are `store_true`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not incredibly familiar with argparse, however from reading the documentation I don't believe there's a way to use `mutually_exclusive_group` and `required` to force this. It seems conditional statements or equivalent are necessary to confirm that valid parameter combinations were passed.

See: [Python Argparse conditionally required arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626109/python-argparse-conditionally-required-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you get rid of most of these arguments, maybe all, and think about standard Unix ways of doing things.

Consider scp, which has a syntax of: **scp** *source destination*

For instance: scp Download/boxfile/xyz.txt qwe.txt

If you don't supply a destination, it infers that you want the file to be called the same thing, and land right here, so these two things are equivalent:

```
scp Download/boxfile/xyz.txt xyz.txt
scp Download/boxfile/xyz.txt
```

Of course, scp can talk to machines across the internet, so there is a format for that:

```
scp hostname:Download/boxfile/xyz.txt xyz.txt
```

And if you are uploading, you simple switch the order:

```
scp xyz.txt hostname:Download/boxfile/xyz.txt
```

Comment: Love that first sentence!