# Python Argparse - conditionally required arguments based on the value of another argument

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to write a daemon service, which can be controlled in the command line. For example, to start the service

`python3 test.py -c start -d /mydownloadfolder/ -j /myconfig.json`

to stop the service,

`python3 test.py -c stop`

The `-d` `-j` parameters are required only when I start the service. Therefore, I need to implement conditionally required arguments based on the value of another argument.

I did some search and found this useful post [Python Argparse conditionally required arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626109/python-argparse-conditionally-required-arguments)
The difference is: instead of checking the existence of '--command', I need to check the value of the '--command'.

Here is my tentative solution:

```
PARSER.add_argument('-c', '--command', required=True, help='provide a valid command: start, stop, restart, or status')
NEED_MORE_ARGS = PARSER.parse_args().command.lower().startswith('start')
PARSER.add_argument('-d', '--download', required=NEED_MORE_ARGS , default=LOCAL_DOWNLOAD, help='set account download folder')
PARSER.add_argument('-j', '--input',  required=NEED_MORE_ARGS, default=JSON_INPUT, help='set input json file')
```

I parsed the args in the middle to get NEED_MORE_ARGS(boolean), and then add other args. The code seems not clean. Is there a better way to do this?

==============

Updated: The tentative solution does not work. :(

Comment: I think the link pretty well covers the options.  There's nothing built into `argparse` that does this kind of cross checking.  I prefer the post-parsing testing option.  But also consider - what kind of `help` do you want to provide?

Comment: I might add that if you don't need the '-c' flag, you could use the subparsers mechanism.  'stop' could then be a subparser without any added arguments, 'start' one with 2 required arguments.

Comment: In the link you mentioned the best answer talks about looking at sys.argv. That makes sense to me. Forget about argparse at first and just check for -c and stop or start in argv. Then use argparse based on what you found in sys.argv. Or just forget argparse and handle sys.argv yourself. Seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use two parsers to do that:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    command_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    command_parser.add_argument('-c', '--command', required=True,
                                help='provide a valid command: start, stop, restart, or status')

    if command_parser.parse_known_args()[0].command.lower().startswith('start'):
        option_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        option_parser.add_argument('-d', '--download', required=True, help='set account download folder')
        option_parser.add_argument('-j', '--input', required=True, help='set input json file')
        option_parser.parse_known_args()
```

or you can use a subparser, which is probably better in your case:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    command_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    subparsers = command_parser.add_subparsers(help='Choose a command')

    start_parser = subparsers.add_parser('start', help='"start" help')
    start_parser.add_argument('-d', '--download', required=True, help='set account download folder')
    start_parser.add_argument('-j', '--input', required=True, help='set input json file')
    start_parser.set_defaults(action=lambda: 'start')

    stop_parser = subparsers.add_parser('stop', help='"stop" help')
    stop_parser.set_defaults(action=lambda: 'stop')

    command_parser.parse_args()
```

in this case command line syntax will be bit different:

```
python3 test.py start -d /mydownloadfolder/ -j /myconfig.json

python3 test.py stop
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion