# How do I take user input which is dependent on other input using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am taking the user input in such a way

```
parser.add_argument("ratio", metavar="fakeratio", type=check_ratio, help="Some fake ratio")
```

here `check_ratio` is method checking if the value is positive and returns float.

**My Question**: I want to add another argument parser asking user to use --f option if the `ratio > 1`. I understand that parser will parse all the arguments in one go. It doesnt have yield (as per my best knowledge). So how can I use --f option if the user has given `ratio >1`. This --f option will not do anything as such. It will just enforce user to use --f if they give value `ratio>1`.

Comment: Would be easier to split out your application logic out of argparser - use the argparser only for raw input arguments and then initialize your application with those values inside code blocks you have full control.

Comment: I realized so. I understood that the argeparse's main job is to take the arguments and any further checks should be at user's discretion. But just for my knowledge, I want to know if there is a way.

Comment: No, there is no way to do [mutually inclusive option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414060/argparse-required-argument-y-if-x-is-present), let alone one with specific conditions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25626676) may point towards something you can attempt to implement.