# Optional suboptions after positonal options argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to achieve something like this:

> python main.py --severity high --start_date 10/12/2016
>
> python main.py --name samuel

Here, the argument **--start_date arg** will only be valid if previous argument is --severity. If we have **--name** instead of **--severity**. The argparse should return error.
How do I achieve this? I have looked for a while and couldn't find something that I wanted to do.

Comment: What would you do if they gave `--severity` after `--start_date`?  Or `--name` along with `--severity`?  `argparse` allows you to enter flagged arguments like this in any order.  If order is important to you, then `argparse` is the wrong tool.

Comment: A `mutually_exclusve_group` can raise an error if `--start_date` is provided along with `--name`, but there isn't a mechanism for `mutually-inclusive` testing.

Comment: A useful prior question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414060/argparse-required-argument-y-if-x-is-present

Comment: @hpauulj severity should always come before start_date.

Comment: The only way to enforce that with `argparse` is to construct one or more custom `Action` classes.  As an exercise I could probably do that, but I wouldn't recommend it for production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `argparse` does not have such capability, so you will have to do it explicitly. Something like this should work:

```
...
args = parser.parse_args()
if getattr(args, 'start_date', None) and not getattr(args, 'severity', None):
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit(1, "error message")
```

Comment: Unless you used `default=SUPPRESS` the namespace will always have a `severity` attribute.  `args.severity is None` is a better test.

Comment: @hpaulj good catch! changed to getattr with default value to make it work in both cases. Though, `if args.start_date and not args.severity:` will be more readable