# python argparse - mandatory sub-command

Tags: python, argparse

I have 3 arguments in and mutually exclusive group. I want to make a new mandatory sub-command available for the '-a' argument and this argument should only be available for the '-a' argument.

What is the best way to do this? I have tried searching and reading this [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) But havent figured it out yet.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='med-tool test', description='med-tool')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
group.add_argument('-a', '--add', help ="Add device", metavar='')
group.add_argument('-d', '--get', help ="Get device", metavar='')
group.add_argument('-r', '--get', help ="Read device", metavar='')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argparse: Required argument 'y' if 'x' is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414060/argparse-required-argument-y-if-x-is-present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `required=True` in `group.add_argument()`.

```
group.add_argument('-a', '--add', help ="Add device", metavar='', required=True)
```

It is described in the docs you linked, **paragraph 15.4.3. The add_argument() method** and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#required).

I am not sure this is really what you want though because it doesn't make sense to add a required argument in a mutually exclusive group.
You probably want to modify it into:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', help ="Add device", metavar='', required=True)
```

Comment: I want to make a new sub-command (argument) available to the '-a' argument. So i guess it should be outside the MEG? 

Like etc: script.py - a test -new house

Comment: Yes, put it outside the MEG.

Comment: Well that was pretty simple ;) Thanks i have it working now.