# python argparse: How to make arguments dependent on choice of another argument

Tags: python, argparse

The python program has multiple options such as download data, build model or both. Example:

```
parser.add_argument('-m', '--mode', required=True, choices=['dload', 'predict', 'both'],
                    help='dload = download data\n '
                         'predict = build prediction model\n,'
                         'both = download and predict')
```

but I want to make sure some of the other arguments are only need to appear when its download. I can easily set `required=False` but that doesn't look like a good solution.

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start-year-month', required=False,
                    help="start year to download data, separate year and month by '- ' "\
                    "ex: 2010-01")

parser.add_argument('-e', '--end-year-month', required=False,
                    help="ending year of data set separate year and month by '- ' " \
                    "ex: 2010-01")
```

above two arguments should only be required when the choice for `-m` is `dload` or `both`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argparse: Required argument 'y' if 'x' is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414060/argparse-required-argument-y-if-x-is-present)

Comment: The default for `optionals` is `required=False`.  If you specify the right defaults for these arguments, it might not matter whether they are provided or not.  You can also test for values after parsing.  The `parser` doesn't have to do all the checking.

Comment: Are 's' and 'e' allowed with 'predict'?  Just not required?  I was thinking of elaborating on the deleted 'sub-commands' answer, but if the only difference is in the 'required' parameter, it may not be worth it.  Stick with your own post-parsing testing.