# Python argparse: optional group of parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I’d like to be able to make a group of parameters mutually exclusive with another parameter (or another group). Something like:

```
program.py [-a alpha] [-b -c gamma -d delta]
```

The requirements are:

- You can use `-a` or `-b` (or both, or none)
- If you use `-b`, you MUST also use `-c` and `-d`

Is it possible at all? I think I could use a sub_parser, but I’m not sure how…

Comment: can't you take n arguements and run through your requirements ?

Comment: `sub_parser` is a great tool, but not applicable here since you want the option of having both `-a` and `-b` or any... using `sub_parser` you can only go down one "branch"

Comment: The provided mutually exclusive mechanism only works with a flat list of parameters.  There isn't a builtin way of applying it to groups.  Usually we recommend doing your own testing after parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414060/argparse-required-argument-y-if-x-is-present) is likely for python2.X, from my research it still holds true. To adapt the answer:

```
if args.b and (args.c is None or args.d is None):
parser.error("--b requires --c and --d.")
```