# How to create dependencies between arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

How do i pass an argument B only if argument A is not None

Example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("A")
parser.add_argument("B") #if A exist
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argparse: Required argument 'y' if 'x' is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414060/argparse-required-argument-y-if-x-is-present)

Comment: Usually do this after parsing.