# Argparse: exception for option required=True

Tags: python, argparse

I use the following code to parse argument to my script (simplified version):

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-l", "--library", required=True)
ap.add_argument("--csv2fasta", required=False)

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

For every way the script can be run, the `-l/--library` flag should be required (`required=True`), but is there a way that it can use the setting `required=False` when you only use the `--csv2fasta` flag?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19414060/2422776

Comment: Sometimes it's simpler to give the "conditionally-required" argument a reasonable `default`, and not worry whether it's been provided or not.  Think about what's simplest (and least error-prone) for your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your test after parsing arguments, here's what I do for such cases:

```py
def parse_args():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-l", "--library")
    ap.add_argument("--csv2fasta")
    args = ap.parse_args()
    if not args.library and not args.csv2fasta:
        ap.error("--library is required unless you provide --csv2fasta argument")
    return args
```

```sh
$ python3 test-args.py
usage: test-args.py [-h] [-l LIBRARY] [--csv2fasta CSV2FASTA]
test-args.py: error: --library is required unless you provide --csv2fasta argument

$ python3 test-args.py --csv2fasta value
```